# Embedding of $W^{1,n}(U)\hookrightarrow L^q(U)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be a $C^1$ bounded region in $\Bbb{R}^n$,we know the Sobolev inequality given as follows:

Asssume $1\le p <n$ for any $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ we have $u\in L^{p^\star}(U)$ where $p^\star = 1/(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n})$.moreover the inequality holds.

$$\|u\|_{L^{q^\star}(U)} \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$$

The question is how to deduced the embedding relationship for $p = n$ that is :
$$W^{1,n}(U)\hookrightarrow L^q(U)$$

For any $1\le q <\infty$

Comment: Are you reading this from Evans'book?

Comment: Yes this result is used in the proof of  of general sobolev inequality  in page 286.without proof.Which says for $u\in W^{k-l,n}(U)$ implies $D^\alpha u \in L^q(U)$ for $|\alpha|\le k-l-1$ exactly the embedding relationship above @James Arten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $L^n(U)\subset L^p(U)$ for $p<n$, $W^{1,n}(U)\subset W^{1,p}(U)\subset L^{p^*}(U)$. Since $p^*\to \infty$ as $p\to n$, the result follows

Comment: Do you mean taking limit for $p\to n$ on both side of  $\|u\|_{L^{q}(U)} \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$? But why taking limit gets the result.There is a point that confuse me since if $q= \infty$ this embedding does not holds

Comment: No, I mean that since $W^{1,n}\subset L^{p^*}$ for every $p$, and $p^*\to\infty$, for some $p$ it holds that $p^*\ge q$, so $W^{1,n}\subset L^q$

Comment: Thanks I got  the argument,since any real number $q$(hence can not be infty) we want,exist some $p$ makes $p^\star  > q$ hence we have $\|u\|_{q} \le C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}} \le C' \|u\|_{W^{1,n}}$ which is the desired result